# Conversion XML => JSON => XML based on a XSD Schema

Tags: java, json, xml, xsd

I saw lots of threads on this topic but not one with an answer.
Is there actually a JAVA library which can make a conversion XML => JSON => XML using an XSD Schema to better handle the problematic of single element in XML.

(a single element in XML can be an array or a single object depending of the XSD schema)

Example for XML :

```
    <root><person><name>test</name></person></root>
```

JSON can be :

```
    {"root": [{"person": [{"name": "test"}]}]}
```

or anything with object instead of array :

```
    {"root": {"person": {"name": "test"}}}
```

But with XSD we would know from the maxoccurs parameters that root is unique, person is an array and name is unique, so the good transformation would be :

```
    {"root": {"person": 
        [{"name": "foofdo"}]
    }}
```

Thx in advance

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what exactly you mean by "the problematic of single element in XML"? Because it's not clear what that problem is. Please provide example XML and JSON to show what you mean.

Comment: I hope it's clearer now, the problem is to determine if a unique element in XML has to be represented as an array or as an object in JSON, and why i can't found any JAVA libraries dealing with this issue using the XSD of the XML document

Comment: The JSON with arrays that you posted is invalid, in an array there are no `key : value` pairs, just values separated by commas.

Comment: There are too many variations in the requirements for one solution to suit everybody. Schema knowledge can help, but only to some extent: for example it can't tell you (except by making educated guesses) whether the order of children within an element is significant. That's why in XSLT 3.0 we decided to provide mechanisms that allow you to roll-your-own transformations, rather than trying to guess your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Java 8** or later, you should check out my open source library: [unXml](https://github.com/tajakobsen/unxml). unXml basically maps from Xpaths to Json-attributes.

It's available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cunxml).

*Example*

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.factory.ParsingFactory;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.parsers.Parser;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Parser {
  public ObjectNode parseXml(String xml){
    Parsing parsing = ParsingFactory.getInstance().create();
    Document document = parsing.xml().document(xml);

    Parser<ObjectNode> parser = parsing.obj("/root/person")
        .attribute("name")
        .build();

    ObjectNode result = parser.apply(document);
    return result;
  }
}
```

It will return a [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) `ObjectNode`, with the following json:

```
{"name":"test"}
```

*Array Example*

Alternativly if you have multiple `person`, you can have it return a [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) `ArrayNode`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.factory.ParsingFactory;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.parsers.Parser;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Parser {
  public ArrayNode parseXml(String xml){
    Parsing parsing = ParsingFactory.getInstance().create();
    Document document = parsing.xml().document(xml);

    Parser<ArrayNode> parser = parsing.arr("/root/person")
        .attribute("name")
        .build();

    ArrayNode result = parser.apply(document);
    return result;
  }
}
```

This will create the following json for your input:

```
[{"name":"test"}]
```